# meteorJS call a shell command from the server

Tags: shell, meteor

I'm using MeteorJS.

I'd like to call a bash command from the javascript server side. This seems possible with nodeJS:
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

However, I can't find something similar with meteorJS. I'd like something like that :

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
...

exec("myCommand");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the calls to require from the sample and prefix them with

```
var sys = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('sys');
```

it should work.

Comment: As of Meteor 0.6.0 it would be something like `var sys = Npm.require('sys');`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use child_process.spawn().

**[Read More about executing a UNIX command with Meteor](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-14-execute-a-unix-command/).**

```
spawn = Npm.require('child_process').spawn;

command = spawn('ls', ['-la']);

command.stdout.on('data',  function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

command.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```