# How to rename a collection in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to rename a collection from code, not from shell, but I find no command,
I know

```
db.originalCollectionName.renameCollection('newCollectionName')
```

but it's only from shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Meteor is built on top of NodeJS, you can use any NodeJS packages and APIs. In your case, you can run your rename command using bash commands in your code using the [Child Process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Julien, the founder of Gentlenode, gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307512/3966682) and wrote this [post](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-14-execute-a-unix-command/33) to describe the process in more details. It is copied below for your convenience.

```
exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('ls -la', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

  if(error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
}

// More concisely
runCommand = function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

  if(error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
}

exec("ls -la", runCommand);
```

In your code, you'd use `mongo --eval "yourcommand()"`. More options can be found in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/). (This will work provided you use the MongoDB already on your machine, and not the one Meteor provides.)

Comment: but mongo is insert into meteor?
i must type "meteor mongo" for access to shell mongo and --eval don't exit. i miss something?
sorry for my bad english :p

Comment: My solution is not perfect because it requires you to run the native MongoDB, instead of the one provided by Meteor, which (and anyone can correct me if I am wrong) is different. You can see how to run your own Mongo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10588038/3966682)