# renameCollection with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I use [renameCollection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) with Meteor? I would like to do this inside Meteor because I need do migrations for development and production environment.

Comment: You can use the Node.js MongoDB driver, but I assume that there will be side effects when used on a running Meteor server (with OpLog tailing and reactivity). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a collection in meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070599/how-to-rename-a-collection-in-meteor)

Answer (score 0):

Use the RemoteCollectionDriver to access the native mongo driver and the instance administraion commands, including the **[`renameCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/#dbcmd.rename)** command.

The following example renames a collection named orders in the `test` database to `orders2016` in the `test` database:

```
var mongoDriver = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver(), // or Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver
    db = mongoDriver.mongo.db;

// for commands not natively supported by the driver - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/
db.command({ renameCollection: "test.orders", to: "test.orders2016" }, function(error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (result.errmsg) {
        console.error('Error calling native renameCollection command:', result.errmsg);
    }
    else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

To implement this server side, you could follow this asynchronous pattern:

```
var shell = function () {
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'),
        future = new Future(),
        db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    db.command({ renameCollection: "test.orders", to: "test.orders2016" }, 
        function(error, result) {
            if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(500, "failed");
            future.return(result);
        }
    );
    return future.wait();
};
```